# Angular resolve not setting ActivatedRoute data

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a resolver; I am new to resolvers, so not sure if I am doing something wrong.
So far, I have this:

```
export class PageResolver implements Resolve<Page>, OnDestroy {
    private pagesSubscription: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(private contentfulService: ContentfulService) {}

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<Page> | Promise<Page> | Page {
        return this.contentfulService.pages.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.pagesSubscription),
            mergeMap((pages: Page[]) => {
                return this.setPage(pages, state.url.split('#')[0]);
            })
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.pagesSubscription.next(true);
        this.pagesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    private setPage(pages: Page[], currentUrl: string): Observable<Page> {
        if (!pages.length || !currentUrl) return;
        let page = pages.find((page: Page) => page.slug === currentUrl);

        if (!page) {
            page = pages.find(
                (page: Page) => currentUrl.indexOf(page.slug) === 0
            );
        }

        console.log(page);

        return of(page);
    }
}
```

My `console.log(page)` is hit when I refresh the page, so that's good.
I have defined my route like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '**', component: HomeComponent, resolve: { page: PageResolver } },
];
```

But in my component I can't seem to access the data:

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
    this.page = this.route.snapshot.data.page;
    console.log(this.page);
    this.onNavigationEnd();
}
```

The home component never seems to fire though, so don't get anything from `console.log(this.route.snapshot.data)`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

If I edit my resolver and change the resolve to this:

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<Page> | Promise<Page> | Page {
    return of(new Page());
}
```

The home component seems to work.

---

Here is the contentfulService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createClient, Entry } from 'contentful';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { Content, Page } from '@models';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ContentfulService {
    private _pages: BehaviorSubject<Page[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Page[]>([]);

    get pages(): Observable<Page[]> {
        return this._pages.asObservable();
    }

    public get current(): Page[] {
        return this._pages.value;
    }

    getPages(): void {
        this.cdaClient
            .getEntries({
                content_type: 'page',
                include: 3,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                this._pages.next(
                    response.items.map((item) =>
                        this.createPage(item, this.createContent)
                    )
                );
            });
    }

    private createPage(page: Entry<any>, createContent: any): Page {
        return {
            title: page.fields['title'],
            slug: page.fields['path'],
            linkText: page.fields['linkText'],
            content: page.fields['content'].map(createContent),
        };
    }

    private createContent(component: Entry<any>): Content {
        return {
            type: component.sys.contentType.sys.id,
            fields: component.fields,
        };
    }

    private cdaClient = createClient({
        space: environment.space,
        accessToken: environment.cdaAccessToken,
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/resolver-route - i replicated your problem almost same here, but it worked

Comment: and this is not an answer but you don't have to unsubscribe the observable using the `takeUntil` operator. `ngOnDestroy` is only available inside a component, so it's not useful in the service.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you are not using a lazy loaded module, but I tried moving mine into the AppModule and adding the route to AppRoutingModule and I still have the same issue. It's really strange that I can resolve if I don't use the mergeMap....

Comment: can you share your contentPage service?

Comment: sure; I have added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.contentfulService.pages` - this is `Observable` of `BehaviourSubject`.

The problem is that Angular router expects the resolve result to be completed.

Just use `take(1)` or `first()` operator so that it can be completed right after:

```js
return this.contentfulService.pages.pipe(
    take(1),
    mergeMap((pages: Page[]) => {
        return this.setPage(pages, state.url.split('#')[0]);
    })
);
```

or

```js
return this.contentfulService.pages.pipe(
    first(),
    mergeMap((pages: Page[]) => {
        return this.setPage(pages, state.url.split('#')[0]);
    })
);
```

Working demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/resolver-route

Comment: I appreciate your help with this, saved me so much time